# How to exclude compile options for one target?

Tags: cmake

I have this in my top-level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3 -march=native -mtune=native -DNDEBUG" )
```

Now, I realized that there is one target for which `-march=native -mtune=native` should be excluded. What is the easiest way to do that? Obviously, I can set these options using [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) for all targets except for the one, but surely there is a less verbose way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern CMake, manually manipulating the [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html) variables is often [discouraged](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/#leave-cmake_cxx_flags-alone). It is better to set these using [`add_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) and [`add_compile_definitions()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html), and you can use generator expressions to control which options apply to the Debug or Release configurations.

**Note**: With this `add_compile_options()` syntax, separate the flags/options with a semicolon `;` since you are using GCC; if you are using Visual Studio's VC++ compiler, spaces should work fine.

```
add_compile_definitions("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:NDEBUG>")    
add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3;-march=native;-mtune=native>")
```

If you have some different Debug options also, you can add those:

```
add_compile_options(
    "$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3;-march=native;-mtune=native>"
    "$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:-O2;-march=something-else>"
)
```

Then, your compilation flags will be accessible via the target property [`COMPILE_OPTIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/COMPILE_OPTIONS.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_OPTIONS), and you can remove the unwanted flags for a specific target using [`string(REPLACE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#replace):

```
get_target_property(MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS MyLib COMPILE_OPTIONS)
if(MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS)
  string(REPLACE "-march=native" "" MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS}")
  string(REPLACE "-mtune=native" "" MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS "${MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS}")
  set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES COMPILE_OPTIONS "${MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS}")
endif()
```

Comment: The generator expression for `add_compile_options()` does not work, the entire string `-O3 -march=native -mtune=native` is passed as one argument in double quotes to the compiler...

Comment: What compiler are you using? This was tested and verified on the Visual Studio C++ compiler.

Comment: Also important: Which version of CMake are you using?

Comment: Either CMake 3.12.2 (Arch Linux) or 3.16.2 (CentOS 7), it behaves the same.

Comment: I think I need to use semicolons instead of spaces, i.e. `add_compile_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O3;-march=native;-mtune=native>")`. There should probably also be quotes around `${MyLib_COMPILE_OPTIONS}` in the `string(REPLACE ...)` commands.

Comment: The semicolons may help, although I'm not in front of a Linux machine at the moment, so I can't test it. Feel free to update the answer, or create a new one if you get something working!

Comment: I think I've finally got it. I've edited your answer.